# Problema con URL Variable PHP - Stripe PHP

Tags: php, url, stripe, webhook

Estoy intentando crear un pasarela de pago con Stripe y PHP. Necesito mandar por URL el ID del pedido y el precio del producto, así:

[image: Example Variable URL]

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Index.php:**

```
<?php
require('config.php');
$v1 = $_GET['importe'];
$v2 = $_GET['pedido'];
echo $v1; echo $v2;
?>
<h1> Click to pay</h1>

<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<?php echo $publishableKey?>"
        data-amount=<?php echo $v1; ?>
        data-name="Trying"
        data-description="ID del producto: <?php echo $v2; ?> "
        data-image="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/RPC-JP_Logo.png"
        data-currency="eur"
        data-email="mail@mail.com"
    >
    </script>

</form>
```

**Submit.php:**

```
<?php
require('config.php');

$v1 = $_GET['importe'];
$v2 = $_GET['pedido'];
echo $v1; echo $v2;

if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){
    \Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);

    $token=$_POST['stripeToken'];

    $data=\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount"=>$v1,
        "currency"=>"eur",
        "description"=>$v2,
        "source"=>$token,
    ));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
}
?>
```

**Config.php:**

```
<?php
require('stripe-php-master/init.php');

$publishableKey="My-Publish-Key";

$secretKey="My-Secret-Key";

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($secretKey);
?>
```

Mi problema es, que puedo la variable de URL en `Index.php`, pero al redirigir a `Submit.php` para pasar los datos `Stripe`, no lo consigo con la URL variable.

```
$data=\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount"=>1000,
        "currency"=>"eur",
        "description"=>$v2,
        "source"=>$token,
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en que no estas mandando los datos al enviar el formulario, no tienes ningún input que mande los valores, además que estas capturando los valores solo cuando los recibes con `GET`, pero no con `POST`, puedes solucionarlo agregando 2 `input` de tipo `hidden` de esta manera y guardando las variables que mandas con `POST`:

#### index.php

```php
<?php

require('config.php');

$v1 = $_GET['importe'];
$v2 = $_GET['pedido'];
echo $v1; echo $v2;

?>

<h1> Click to pay</h1>

<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="importe" value="<?php echo($v1); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="pedido" value="<?php echo($v2); ?>">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<?php echo $publishableKey?>"
        data-amount=<?php echo $v1; ?>
        data-name="Trying"
        data-description="ID del producto: <?php echo $v2; ?> "
        data-image="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/RPC-JP_Logo.png"
        data-currency="eur"
        data-email="mail@mail.com"
    >
    </script>

</form>
```

#### submit.php

```php
<?php
require('config.php');

$v1 = $_POST['importe'];
$v2 = $_POST['pedido'];
echo $v1; echo $v2;

if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])){
    \Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);

    $token=$_POST['stripeToken'];

    $data=\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount"=>$v1,
        "currency"=>"eur",
        "description"=>$v2,
        "source"=>$token,
    ));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
}

?>
```